# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established with angular node js and Nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to build a socket.io app with angular and nodeJs. While the app works perfectly fine in local, It fails to connect if we deploy it in Kubernaties cluster with Nginx proxy.Throws `WebSocket is closed before the connection is established error`.
i am using **socket.io-client**  as clientside library and **socket.io** as server side.

Server side :

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/terminal'));

const server = http.createServer(app)
const port = 3100;
const io = socketIO(server,
  {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
      }
    );
server.listen(port);
```

client - angular component.ts

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
export class component {
                ...
    
        connectToSocket() {
                  return new Promise(res => {
                    const socket = io('/socketService',{query: { ops: value}},);
                    res(socket);
                  });
                }
              ...
    }
```

Proxy Config change

```
"/socketService": {
    "target": "https://NginxService:8080/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
```

NGINX config

```
location /socketService/ {
            access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/auth.lua;
                proxy_pass  http://socketService:3100;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
```

in Kubernetes gateway i have whitelisted this path `('/socketService')`.I have already tried most of the Stackoverflow solutions.But none of them worked out for me . Could anyone please help ?

versions:

- socket.io - ^4.6.2
- socket.io-client - ^4.6.2

**WHAT i tried so far**

1. Attaching headers in socket client connection Options.

   { extraHeaders: { Accept: "application/json",'Content-Type': "*/*", Authorization: `Bearer TOKEN}`}
2. Changing the type from long plling to websocket in Options.

   Transports: ['websocket']
3. Since my app runs on SSL ,tried passing this in Options

   RejectUnauthorized: false
4. Adding Path : path: "/socket.io" (not needed , defaults to socket.io)

URL : `wss://localhost:4200/socket.io/?ops=null&EIO=4&transport=websocket`

Error screenshot:
[image]